# C++ Codeblocks + libcurl ends up with link errors

Tags: c++, curl, codeblocks, libcurl

Hi I am a C++ beginner and I wanted to learn about http requests...
 I picked cURL because I have experience using it before with php.
I downloaded this version from cURL website into **C:\libs**
    Win64 x86_64 7zip   7.51.0  binary  SSL     SSH     Viktor Szakáts  1.81 MB

This is what I've done so far on Codeblocks:

1. Under Global compiler settings/Search directories/Compiler, I added this path:
   C:\libs\curl-7.51.0-win64-mingw\include\curl
2. Under Global compiler settings/Search directories/Linker, I added this path:
   C:\libs\curl-7.51.0-win64-mingw\lib
3. Under Global compiler settings/Linker settings, I added this paths:
   C:\libs\curl-7.51.0-win64-mingw\lib\libcurl.a
   C:\libs\curl-7.51.0-win64-mingw\lib\libcurldll.a

-Under Global compiler settings/compiler settings, this box is checked from before:
Have g++ follow the C++11 standard... (no idea if this matters or not...)

Also, because I was desperate I copied the contents of C:\libs\curl-7.51.0-win64-mingw to C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW, this step makes no sense to me, but I found it online so I tried...

Now I am running this code:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl.h>
#include <easy.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){

CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
if(!curl){
        cout << "error" << endl;
    }else{
     cout << "good job!" << endl;
     curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
};
```

I am getting this errors:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
error: ld returned 1 exit status
Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

For some reason, including include curl/curl.h does not work, only way it works is including curl.h, same for easy.h

Any advice appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since "any advice" was solicited, the best advice I can give is to use Linux. curl is standard package in all Linux distributions, and does not need to be installed manually.

Comment: At this point, you should just use a unix system.

Comment: Make your title describe the question.

Comment: @self: That's not helpful.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. If someone can actually help I am still searching!

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?
I am having exactly the same issue and cannot find anything on the Internet.

Answer (score 2):

You're linking with a static libcurl (on Windows) without having `-DCURL_STATICLIB` added to your `CFLAGS` when you build your application.

That is, you **must** define `CURL_STATICLIB` before the curl headers are included.

Described in the curl FAQ item [Link errors when building libcurl on Windows](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#Link_errors_when_building_libcur)

Comment: The curl guy himself!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't get it. Can you explain what to do exactly?

Comment: This is very unhelpful. The FAQ is very vague I don't understand anything from it and you refused to provide clarification when asked by OP.